# is using a constant without an explicit cast invoke undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c, function, undefined-behavior

Upon invoking a function,or returning a value from a function,that expects a value of type `T`,does using a constant literal without explicit cast invoke undefined behavior?

For example,we have a function who's prototype is `long foo(unsigned long x);`
Invocation: `foo(4); //does this invoke UB?`

`long foo(unsigned long x) { x += 10; return 10; } // does this invoke UB ?`

should we write `foo((unsigned long)4)` and `return (long)10` ??

Comment: _`foo(4); //does this invoke UB?`_ No.

Comment: C **or** C++? That is important!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you think it might be undefined? It's probably okay if there isn't, but it's still good to know.

Comment: @hvd I sometimes see casts on constants and i wondered if not casting is well defined

Comment: @layzak Then another approach might be to pick a concrete example where the cast is present, think about whether it would be okay to remove the cast in that situation, and if you can't come up with an answer (can't convince yourself it's okay), ask that, instead of asking the more general question of whether the cast is always required with the most basic example you can find. Although the example you've picked isn't one of them, there are scenarios where casting constants as function arguments is useful and/or required.

Comment: If the `foo` prototype is an old-school parameterless prototype (applies only to C), then you do need to cast the parameter.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It might in C

Comment: @RaymondChen A prototype always declares the parameter types (or `void` in C)  ; you're describing a *non-prototype declaration*

Comment: It’s ok/ no need to casting.

As, you are functioning with unsigned long inside foo, be cautious if you want to return x.
If x is large enough to hold in long, you are going to receive an unexpected value.

Comment: in C, the concept of automatic parameter promotion and the concept of implicit conversion will result in the correct value being see inside the function AND (usually) return the correct value type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is all well-defined.

There exists an implicit conversion rule between the two types, so the `int` is simply converted to an `unsigned long` and the program works as expected.

Comment: Because there is no cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. I probably should have put that in the edit comment.

Answer (score 3):

Type of literal `4` is `int`. (In C section 6.4.4.1 Integer constants, similar section available in C++ also)

Implicit conversion from `int` to `unsigned long` is well defined in both C and C++. (In C section 6.3.3.1)

> should we write foo((unsigned long)4) and return (long)10?

Both of your example are well defined, so this conversion though acceptable is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this C code:

```
// foo.c
int foo(unsigned long x) { }
```

and

```
// main.c
int foo();

int main()
{
     foo(4);    // UB
     foo((unsigned long)4);   // OK
}
```

The `foo(4)` call is UB because when you are calling a function with no prototype in scope, you must manually make sure the parameters match.  The *default argument promotions* occur but that's all.

Of course, writing the cast is a bad solution from the point of view of writing robust code. The better solution would be to write a prototype:

```
int foo(unsigned long);
```

in a header file which is included from both the `.c` files.

---

The `return 10;` case can never be UB because the function's true return type is known to the compiler when it is compiling the code inside the function body.

Answer (score 0):

No, it wouldn't make sense, since such argument is passed *by value* in both C and C++:

```
long foo(unsigned long x);
```

You may think of it technicaly as `x` parameter is a local automatic variable defined inside `foo` and assigned with the value of passed argument:

```
unsigned long x = 4;
```

If type of argument does not match with parameter, then compiler tries with implicit conversion. For instance, an argument of type `double` is silenty converted into of type `unsigned long`, even it means loss of information (you might get a compiler warning though).

You may however get into trouble, when you mark type of `x` parameter as *reference* (C++ only):

```
long foo(unsigned long& x);
```

Here, the compiler would not allow you to call it as `foo(4)`, because you are now passing by reference, and `4` cannot be modified as such. You may however pass it if the parameter is marked with `const` qualifier:

```
long foo(const unsigned long& x);
```